# VS Code colors suddenly stopped working, how do I fix this issue?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm a student and using VS Code to learn. When I opened a new file today, all the coloration from the code was gone. I'm using Dark+ theme and have the C++ intellisense extension active. I've checked color themes, uninstalled/reinstalled, restarting, disabling and re-enabling the extensions.
Included is a screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmrKr.png

Comment: Look in the status bar. You chose "Plain Text" language mode which has no highlighting. Click it and pick C++.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much! It didn't bring back all the colors, but it brought back some of them. For example, "cout" used to be teal, and a cmath function like "pow" used to be red. Any idea on those?

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me, but in my case, I was using React and my language mode wasn't in Plain Text.

[image]

I started checking my extensions, and noticed that probably the problem was this typescript extension: **JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly**

[image]

I've disabled the extension and VSCode colors worked properly again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your file extension is ".ccp" instead of ".cpp" so vscode recognized it as plain text.
Change the file extension to ".cpp" may solve the problem.